# Elasticsearch comparison OR

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must": [
                { "match": { "tags": "htc" } },
                { "match": { "votype" : 1} },
                { "match": { "subtype": 1 } },
                { "match": { "deleted": 0 } },
                { "match": { "build_status": 4 } },
                { "match": { "publish": 1 } }
            ]
        }
    },

    "sort": [
        { "created": "desc" }
    ],

    "size": 30,
    "from": 0
}
```

and i want put into value list of values

```
{ "match": { "votype": [1 or 2 or 3] } }
```

SQL analog:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE type IN(1, 2);
```

but don `t know how to

don't work:

```
{ "match": { "votype": [1,3] } },
{ "match": { "votype": "1 2" } },
{ "match": { "votype": "1OR2" } }
```

Comment: Have a look at the [terms query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-query.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must": [
                { "terms" : { "tags": ["htc"], "minimum_match": 1 } },
                { "terms" : { "votype" : [1,2], "minimum_match": 1 } },
                { "terms" : { "deleted": [0], "minimum_match": 1 } },
                { "terms" : { "build_status": [4], "minimum_match": 1 } },
                { "terms" : { "publish": [1], "minimum_match": 1 } }
            ]

        }
    },

    "sort": [
        { "created": "desc" }
    ],

    "size": 30,
    "from": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
{ "match": { "votype": "1 2 3" } }
```

Comment: I thought the question was "how to search for a list of value in a match query?" and I think I answered to this question. I don't see what's wrong with my answer. Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @dadoonet Sorry, I was a little quick on the trigger here.